# Is there a way to browse the edits I made only to the posts that are not mine?

Tags: discussion, edits

I can [look](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2963652/nicael?tab=activity&sort=revisions) at all revs I ever made. How to filter only ones that were made to the posts that don't belong to me? Maybe a query in data explorer?

Comment: [I whipped this Data Explorer query together](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/238863/all-user-edits-that-isnt-on-their-post). It should get you the data you're after, or give you a starting point.